# How to set cell background color in grid/table in view in Vaadin?

Tags: java, gridview, grid, vaadin

I am using Vaadin and I would like to set backgroung color to specific cell in my grid/table or if there is no possible to set background color to specific cell I would like to at least set a font color to specific cell in grid/table. The code TableView where I have got a grid/table is below:

```
package com.trading.scraper;

import com.vaadin.navigator.View;
import com.vaadin.ui.CustomComponent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Grid;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class TableView extends CustomComponent implements View {

    static final String NAME = "Stock table";

    TableView() {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();

        List<Stock> people = Arrays.asList(
                new Stock("1", "2", "1"),
                new Stock("3", "5", "2"),
                new Stock("1", "3", "4"));

        Grid<Stock> grid = new Grid<>();
        grid.setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
        grid.setItems(people);
        grid.addColumn(Stock::getValue1).setCaption("Value1");
        grid.addColumn(Stock::getValue2).setCaption("Value2");
        grid.addColumn(Stock::getValue3).setCaption("Value3");

        layout.addComponents(grid);
        setCompositionRoot(layout);
    }
}
```

The content class for grid/table is:

```
package com.trading.scraper;

public class Stock {

    private String value1;
    private String value2;
    private String value3;

    public String getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }

    public void setValue1(String value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }

    public String getValue2() {
        return value2;
    }

    public void setValue2(String value2) {
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    public String getValue3() {
        return value3;
    }

    public void setValue3(String value3) {
        this.value3 = value3;
    }

    public Stock() {
    }

    Stock(String value1, String value2, String value3) {
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
        this.value3 = value3;
    }
}
```

If it is possible to set background color to specific cell or at least set font color and you know how to do it please write. E.g. where cell's value in grid/table is "1" I would like to make it red but if e.g. cell's value is "5" I would like to make it green and if cell's value is "3" I would like to make it yellow. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options to style the content of a `Grid` in Vaadin.

First, to set the style of a row, you can do the following:

```
grid.setStyleGenerator(stockRow -> 
  "1".equals(stockRow.getValue1()) ? "highlighted" : null);
```

The css class `highlighted` will be added to each grid row, were the condition applies. You can then style the row in SCSS using the following selector:

```
.v-grid-row.highlighted {
  color: red;
}
```

To select and style the cells, you need to select the td's:

```
.v-treegrid-row.highlighted > td {
  color: red;
}
```

I guess you'd want to style the cells directly so it would be more appropriate to set the style generator on a per-column mode as in following example:

```
grid
  .addColumn(Stock::getValue1)
  .setCaption("Value1")
  .setStyleGenerator(stockRow -> {
    switch (stockRow.getValue1()) {
      case "1": return "red";
      case "3": return "yellow";
      case "5": return "green";
      default: return null;
    }
  });
```

You can then style the cells in SCSS:

```
.v-grid-cell.red {
  color: red;
}
```