# Vaadin 8 changing background color of grid cell

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

How can i paint grid cell in Vaadin 8 or above. As Vaadin 8 doesn't support grid.setCellStyleGenerator anymore, I don't know what else to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set cell background color in grid/table in view in Vaadin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48228531/how-to-set-cell-background-color-in-grid-table-in-view-in-vaadin). `grid.setCellStyleGenerator` is still supported up to the current version (8.3.1) as mentioned in Tatu Lund's answer, so you can apply the same technique as in the linked question

Answer (score 3):

> As Vaadin 8 doesn't support grid.setCellStyleGenerator anymore

No, the style generator is still supported, see documentation here

https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.3/8.3.1/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.html#setStyleGenerator-com.vaadin.ui.StyleGenerator-

You can set style generator also column wise, see here

https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.3/8.3.1/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.Column.html#setStyleGenerator-com.vaadin.ui.StyleGenerator-