# How to get the applied backgroundcolor from a Row and a Cell of Vaadin TreeGrid/Grid?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

Im using the Vaadin version 8.6.4 for Java and I have a dataset that is represented on a TreeGrid. Until now I could not get the styleName that is applied to any row or any cell.  There is any method or trick to get the actual style of a cell/row in vaadin? The list of styles are added like the code that is below.

I though also setting an Id to all cells before the Grid get created by overrideing the intern method of Grid Class. After that i should be able to fired a Javascript function on the client-side for searching the style of a cell by its id. But all that has been so complicated, so I have not been successful.

```
final String reservationColor  = "background-color: "green" !important;";   
final String STYLENAME_RESERVED = "reserved";

Styles styles = Page.getCurrent().getStyles();
styles.add(".v-treegrid-cell." + STYLENAME_RESERVED +"{"+ reservationColor + "}");
```

Answer (score -1):

TreeGrid is directly exteding Grid, so you should be able to use similar methods to style the TreeGrid.

The preferred way to e.g. change cell background color is to use style generator

There is already question about that here with answer: [How to set cell background color in grid/table in view in Vaadin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48228531/how-to-set-cell-background-color-in-grid-table-in-view-in-vaadin)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but  I dont want to set a backgroundcolor for a cell. I want to GET the style of that cell.

Comment: I would recommend to maintain info about that on serverside, and use that info also in style generator to define the stylename to be used. Then you do not need to check the stylename directly.

Comment: Sure. The problem is i want to create a xlsx representation of the TreeGrid and some rows have important colors. There is a way to know which style/backgroundcolor has any cell of the grid? this happens on server side.

Comment: Q: There is a way to know which style/backgroundcolor has any cell of the grid? A: There is no server side API for that. That is why I proposed the other method to set the background color, and maintain that info in your data model instead. I think from software architecture perspective it is more correct way to do also.